# Alfresco accepting only .txt files while uploading and giving 500 internal server error for other files

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts, alfresco-enterprise

Today I found very wearied behavior of alfresco,  When I upload any .txt file via share UI, its getting uploaded successfully, but if I upload any other type of file then it's giving 500 internal server error as shown in attached screen shot, also you can see in the image that .txt file got uploaded successfully.

The strange thing is there is no any error in the server logs.

Doe's anyone faced similar issue?
Also it is working for .txt, so is it a issue of Transformation?

Please suggest the possibilities of error.

Thanks in Advance.

[image]

**Error while uploading through CMIS workbench:**

[image]

Comment: What Alfresco version are you using? Are you use default Alfresco or with some addons? Can you share logs from browser debug  (networking)?

Comment: We are using alfresco 5.2.2.2 Enterprise, Also we are using Uploader+ addon

Comment: Can you share uploader plus configuration from Share's admin tools?

Comment: Is there a chance of issue in uploader plus, as I said .txt files are getting uploaded fine, there is issue with other type of files like pdf, doc, images etc.

Comment: Doe's anyone have Idea, when Alfresco allowing only .txt and not allowing other format files?? What can be the cause for this?

Comment: Pls share your configuration,
e.g https://github.com/softwareloop/uploader-plus/wiki/Configuration

Answer (score 2):

It does sound like a transformation problem to me, but it is hard to be sure.

Because TXT files are working that means there isn't a problem with your repo being read-only or something like that. If these were office files, especially if they were large, you might be hitting a configurable transformer limit.

I would try uploading the problem files using something other than Share, such as:

- Alfresco FTP
- Alfresco WebDAV
- Alfresco CIFS/SMB
- Apache Chemistry Workbench

Using any (or all) of these will give you a clue as to whether the problem is in Share or lower in the stack.

Comment: I am getting same error through CMIS workbench, and not able to upload documents, please find attached screen shots in the question body. please update your views.

Comment: Try uninstalling the uploader plus repository AMP and see if the problem persists.